# TypeError: db.transaction is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.aggregateRatings = functions.firestore
    .document('destinations/{destId}/reviews/{reviewId}')
    .onWrite(event => {

const reviewRating = event.data.get('reviewRating');    
const destinationId = event.params.destId;
const destRef = db.collection('destinations').doc(destinationId);

return db.transaction(transaction => { 
    return transaction.get(destRef).then(destDoc => {
        const numberOfReviews = destDoc.data('numberOfReviews') + 1;

        var oldRatingTotal = destDoc.data('destinationRating') * destDoc.data('numberOfReviews');
        var newAvgRating = (oldRatingTotal + reviewRating) / numberOfReviews;

        return transaction.update(destRef, {
            destinationRating: newAvgRating,
            numberOfReviews: numberOfReviews
        });
     });
  });
});
```

When the firebase function is called i get this error, but I have no idea why this is happening..Could someone help me? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method name you're looking for is [runTransaction](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/Firestore#runTransaction) (not "transaction").

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly, but then i guess the following documentation is outdated https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation

Comment: @Vachi If you read that entire page you see both functions being used. runTransaction in firestore client and transaction in cloud functions.

Comment: Yeah, one of the samples is wrong.  I'll see if I can get that corrected.